# 1013: The private attribute may be used only on class property definitions

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I'm trying to get my movieclip to jump automatically back to frame 1 as soon as it lands on the final frame.
I labeled the final frame as "final_frame", the title is the error I'm getting and this is the code I used:

```
private function handleTimelineEvent(e:TimelineEvent):void {
            if (e.currentLabel === final_frame) {
                gotoAndStop(1);     
            }
}
```

Am I making an obvious mistake? Also, if there's an easier/better way to do this, I'll be glad to hear it!

Comment: remove "private", the error says it all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The class property descriptors can only be used in class files (external .as files).    These descriptors (keywords) include:  `private` `protected` `public` `static` and `internal`.    see [documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f32.html) for more details

Since you are using timeline code (which automatically creates it's own class file for you behind the scenes), you need to strip out all these keywords.

In your case, just removing the keyword `private` from your function declaration will do the trick.  So it should look like this:

```
function handleTimelineEvent(e:TimelineEvent):void {
    if (e.currentLabel === final_frame) {
        gotoAndStop(1);     
    }
}
```